# $\bigcup_{n\ge n_0}f_n^{-1}(\infty)$ is closed and discrete: is my proof correct?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, proof-verification

Let $D\subseteq\Bbb C$ open and $\{f_n\}_{n\ge n_0}\subseteq\mathcal{M}(D)$ a sequence of meromorphic functions on $D$.

Then I have to prove that
$A:=\bigcup_{n\ge n_0}f_n^{-1}(\infty)$ is closed and discrete **in $D$**.

To prove $A$ is discrete in $D$, I have to prove that $\operatorname{Acc}_D(A)=\emptyset$, i.e. $A$ has no accumulation points in $D$.

Supposing I have proved this (which is the tricky part; but I'm pretty sure about its correctness), to prove it is closed in $D$, I wrote
$$
\operatorname{Cl}_D(A):=A\cup\operatorname{Acc}_D(A)
$$
which is equal to $A$ (since the least set is empty) which is thus closed.

Is this argument right?

Comment: ?? If $n_0=0$ and $D=C$ and $f_n(z)=(z-2^{-n})^{-1}$ for $n\in N$ then $A=\{2^{-n}:n\in N\}$ is not closed. Also, what is the "least set" and why is it empty?

Comment: @user254665 he means the last set (in the union formula for the closure), which he has claimed to have shown to be empty.

Comment: @user254665 it does seem like a legit counterexample. So maybe the original statement is not true.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma . I think the Q is mis-stated, but I dk in what way.

Comment: So, down below we have a confirm of my proof, and here above we have a counterexample. How can we get out from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a set with no accumulation points is always closed. This is because of $\operatorname{Acc}_D(A) \subseteq A$ iff $A$ is closed. Or from your closure formula as well.

Showing $\operatorname{Acc}_D(A)$ empty shows two things at once: closed and discrete. For discreteness alone it is necessary to show that $\operatorname{Acc}_D(A) \cap A = \emptyset$, i.e. no point of $A$ itself is an accumulation point.

So showing $\operatorname{Acc}_D(A)$ empty means that $A$ is discrete in itself, as it's disjoint from $A$, and closed, as it's a subset of $A$ as well.

E.g. $D = \mathbb{C}, A = \{\frac{1}{n}: n =1,2,\ldots \}$ is discrete (as $\operatorname{Acc}_D(A) = \{0\}$ and $\{0\} \cap A = \emptyset$) but not closed, as $\{0\} \nsubseteq A$. And $B = A \cup \{0\}$ is closed (same $\operatorname{Acc}_D(B) = \{0\} \subseteq B$) but not discrete as $\{0\} \cap B = \{0\} \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: I've edited... sorry for the typo!

Comment: MANY MANY THANKS! This is exactly the answer I've hoped for!

Comment: Glad to be able to help!